# Cannot connect to SQL Server on Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have installed Docker Desktop on my local machine with a docker-compose.yml file.
This seems to run fine and i get a database loaded (see attached screenshot)

[image]

However when I try to connect i get the following error message  (show in attached screenshot):

> Login failed for user 'sa'.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file; what am I doing wrong here?

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  sql-server:

restart: unless-stopped
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
container_name: sql-server
environment:

  - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
  - SA_PASSWORD=MyPass@word
  - MSSQL_PID=Express
  - MSSQL_COLLATION=Latin1_General_CI_AS
  - MSSQL_BACKUP_DIR=/usr/share/sql_backup
  - MSSQL_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/sql_data
  - MSSQL_LOG_DIR=/usr/share/sql_log
  - MSSQL_DUMP_DIR=/usr/share/sql_dump
  - MSSQL_MASTER_DATA_FILE=/usr/share/sql_master/master.mdf
  - MSSQL_MASTER_LOG_FILE=/usr/share/sql_master/mastlog.ldf
  - MSSQL_ERROR_LOG_FILE=/usr/share/sql_data/sql_error_log.ldf

ports:

  - 1433:1433

volumes:

  - C:\ChrisDev\Databases\sql_server:/usr/share/sql_data
  - C:\ChrisDev\Databases\sql_server\logs:/usr/share/sql_log
  - C:\ChrisDev\Databases\sql_server\dumps:/usr/share/sql_dump
  - C:\ChrisDev\Databases\sql_server\backup:/usr/share/sql_backup
  - C:\ChrisDev\Databases\sql_server\master:/usr/share/sql_master
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue may be. Did you check the container logs? You can find it by clicking the container in Docker Desktop, or by typing `docker logs sql-server` in a terminal.

Comment: Are you sure the SQL Server instance you want to connect is actually listening on 1433, and it's not a different instance?

Comment: If you check the  mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation you'll notice that the sa password is configured using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable (the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable got phased out a while back). Also be careful of special characters here because they might need shell-escaped to get through to SQL Server unaffected.

Comment: Have you inspected the container's log output to see if any errors occurred during the SQL Server startup sequence? (Just because the container is running doesn't mean the SQL Server service inside it is.)

Comment: Aside... the path for the `errorlog` file, set by the `MSSQL_ERROR_LOG_FILE` environment variable, is not an .ldf format file. It's a regular old text file capturing the same information you'd see in the container's log output.

Comment: Ok I changed the ports to 5433:5433 and the password variable to MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD

error:
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------
Cannot connect to localhost,5433.
------------------------------
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10054-database-engine-error

Comment: Hi there 

I have figured this out. 

what I needed to do was to modify my ports as follows:

    ports:

      - 1436:1433

Then I can connect through SSMS as localhost,1436